# Node.js: Creating 8 byte buffer

Tags: arrays, node.js, byte, buffer

I am looking to translate a Python snippet to Node.js. The Python code looks like this:

```
NULL_CHAR = chr(0)

def write_report(report):
    with open('/dev/hidg0', 'rb+') as fd:
        fd.write(report.encode())

# write_report(<byte1> + <byte3> + <byte4> + <bytes5-8>)
write_report(chr(32)+NULL_CHAR+chr(11)+NULL_CHAR*5)
```

As you can see the Python code quite intuitively constructs the 8 byte report.

How can I do this same thing in Node.js? My current guess is to use the buffer class:

```
const data = Buffer.from([0x20, 0x0, 0xB, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0]);
```

so altogether:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var file = '/dev/hidg0'

const data = Buffer.from([0x20, 0x0, 0xB, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0]);

fs.writeFile(file, data, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

Is this the right way to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure enough, the answer is in the questions - it works